# how to debug karmatests?

Tags: angularjs, visual-studio, karma-jasmine

I just starting using karma unit tests written in Jasmine. Also using vs.net 2013, with angular js on the client. How can I debug my unit tests? I tried to set breakpoints in vs.net and I cannot open the devtools in the browser?

Answer (score 0):

Set singlerun flag to false in karma config. Now browser will stay opened between test sessions. Open developer tools and debug as usually. Also there is "debug" button on top right, but it dont want to work properly.
[image: Example of debugging]